How to efficiently filter a large list in Python using multiple conditions?
I'm working on a Python project where I need to filter a large list of dictionaries based on multiple conditions.
Here's a simplified example of the data structure I'm dealing with:
data = [
    {"name": "David", "age": 30, "city": "Nairobi"},
    {"name": "Shanice", "age": 25, "city": "Kisumu"},
    {"name": "Shon", "age": 35, "city": "Mombasa"},
    # ... potentially thousands of more entries
]

I want to filter this list to include only those entries where the age is greater than 28 and the city is either "Nairobi" or "Mombasa". My current approach is to use a list comprehension like this:
filtered_data = [
    entry for entry in data
    where entry['age'] > 28 and entry['city'] in ('Nairobi', 'Mombasa')
]

While this works for smaller lists, performance becomes an issue with larger datasets. Is there a more efficient way to perform this filtering, especially for very large lists?
Any suggestions or best practices for optimizing this kind of operation would be greatly appreciated!

use pandas querry or loc with condition

How large are your larger datasets, how long does it take then, and how fast would it have to be to not be an issue?

Except for the where and perhaps the tuple, that example code looks alright. Maybe your real code is slow because you did something bad there that we can't see?

The larger datasets I work with can range up to 100,000 entries.Filtering such a dataset currently takes several seconds.Ideally, the filtering process should take less than a second to avoid bottlenecks in my application.

I just tried with that many entries and it only takes about 0.01 seconds.

If this is something you are going to do more than once or twice, then I would reshape the data to be a dictionary with keys of city and values of list of dictionaries.

100,000 items is tiny, and the code you posted should work very fast

Of course, there is always the alternative of turning to a proper database with robust query support and indexing, but that aside, if you wanted to do something simple with what you have and these types of searches were something you were going to do more than once or twice, then I would reshape the list into something that lends itself to your search.
def build_search(data):
    lookup = {}
    for row in data:
        lookup.setdefault(row["city"], []).append(row)
    return lambda city, age: [row for row in lookup.get(city, []) if row["age"] > age]

data = [
    {"name": "David", "age": 30, "city": "Nairobi"},
    {"name": "Shanice", "age": 25, "city": "Kisumu"},
    {"name": "Shon", "age": 35, "city": "Mombasa"},
    # ... potentially thousands of more entries
]
search =  build_search(data)

print(search("Nairobi", 22))
print(search("Cairo", 22))
print(search("Nairobi", 22) + search("Kisumu", 22))

Should give you:
[{'name': 'David', 'age': 30, 'city': 'Nairobi'}]
[]
[{'name': 'David', 'age': 30, 'city': 'Nairobi'}, {'name': 'Shanice', 'age': 25, 'city': 'Kisumu'}]

If you were keen to pass a list of cities rather than building the result by list addition, then you might use yield like:
def build_search(data):
    lookup = {}
    for row in data:
        lookup.setdefault(row["city"], []).append(row)

    def work(cities, age):
        for city in cities:
            for person in lookup.get(city, []):
                if person["age"] > age:
                    yield person

    return work

data = [
    {"name": "David", "age": 30, "city": "Nairobi"},
    {"name": "Shanice", "age": 25, "city": "Kisumu"},
    {"name": "Shon", "age": 35, "city": "Mombasa"},
    # ... potentially thousands of more entries
]
search =  build_search(data)

print(list(search(["Nairobi", "Kisumu"], 22)))

that should give you:
[{'name': 'David', 'age': 30, 'city': 'Nairobi'}, {'name': 'Shanice', 'age': 25, 'city': 'Kisumu'}

